Histogram of Location of Rows that contain missing values
I'm try to create a histogram of location of rows that contain missing values for House-Prices-Advanced-Regression-Technique using this approach on python.
Following is the histogram that I want

But when I try to do train.isnull().sum(axis=1).plot(kind='hist', use_index=True), I get 
I would appreciate if you can help.

always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

@aditt if the solution has helped, kindly consider marking it as correct. If it hasn't, then it's okay. Thank you.

You can create an extra column in the train dataframe "missing" that will hold value 0 if there aren't any missing values or 1 for missing values. Then, use this column to create your histogram.
train['missing'] = train.isnull().any(axis=1)

#Plotting the histogram using matplotlib
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.hist(train.index[train['missing'] == 1], bins=len(train))
plt.show() 

You can customize the bin size according to your requirement. Hope this helps.
